# Getting undefined is not an object when using react-native's FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Recently began to study React Native. Now I try to display an array of objects on the page. I did everything as if right, but I get an error:

```
Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'task.name'
```

I have two questions, what am I doing wrong and why in React Native, elements are displayed using FlatList and not via the map method? Here is my code snippet:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function Tasks() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "By Bread" },
    { id: 2, name: "By pizza" },
    { id: 3, name: "By snack" },
  ]);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList data={tasks} renderItem={({ task }) => <Text key={id}>{task.name}</Text>} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `item` instead of `task` because `renderItem` gets as parameter an object with `item` holding the current row from `data` array. Like so:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function Tasks() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "By Bread" },
    { id: 2, name: "By pizza" },
    { id: 3, name: "By snack" },
  ]);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={tasks}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is `renderItem`'s destructed signature from the official [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-renderitem):

```
renderItem({ item, index, separators });
```

Also you have a `key = {id}` on  `Text` that you don't need.