# FlatList render item function does not let access passed parameters properties

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am making an API call to a .NET Core API from a React Native App with Axios. On one screen I had the similar code that works perfectly but it does not work here and throws an error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'request.title')]
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Lists\FlatList.js:597:25 in renderer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Lists\FlatList.js:629:25 in virtualizedListRenderKey
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Lists\VirtualizedList.js:2008:23 in CellRenderer#_renderElement
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Lists\VirtualizedList.js:2033:20 in CellRenderer#render
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13725:21 in finishClassComponent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13654:43 in updateClassComponent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20692:22 in beginWork$1
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19855:22 in performUnitOfWork
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19783:21 in workLoopSync
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19753:18 in renderRootSync
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19445:33 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5975:29 in flushSyncCallbacks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5954:22 in flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19016:42 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11583:36 in dispatchAction
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:248:12 in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:112:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:162:14 in _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:413:41 in callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:405:6 in __callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:133:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:382:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:132:4 in flushedQueue
```

Here is the code that I wrote to implement a render function and the actual FlatList Component that is to call that method to render items:

```
const renderList = (request) => {
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(request.id + ", " + typeof(request.id))}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.itemInfoContainer}>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{request.title}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.description}>{request.description}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }

    return(
        <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
            <FlatList 
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={requests}
                keyExtractor={request => request.id}
                renderItem={({request}) => renderList(request)}            
            />
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting undefined is not an object when using react-native's FlatList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360493/getting-undefined-is-not-an-object-when-using-react-natives-flatlist)

Comment: yes it does. David said the same thing  but I think its stupid really that it only works when item is passed and not some other parameter name.

Comment: It is not “stupid”, it is how JS works. The `renderItem` prop receives a function. This function receives an input parameter. This input parameter is an object. This object contains a property called `item`. You are using destructuring to access this property. Hence you need to access it with the specified name.

Comment: To be precise here. When you pass a function to a component, the name of the input parameter is not defined. There is no difference in this case. `renderItem={(hello) => …}` is totally valid. However, `renderItem={({test}) => …` will not work. In the second case we are trying to destructure a property called test from the input parameter of the provided function. This property is not defined. In the first case we are providing a name for the whole object. This name is not well defined. We can name it to whatever we want.

Comment: For example: `const obj = { item: “test“}` is a JS object saved inside a variable named obj. This object defines a property called item . We can destructure it as follows: `const { item } = obj`. We can access the item property of the object. However, `const { test } = obj` will do nothing. The property test does not exist for obj. This is precisely what happens in your example.

Comment: @DavidScholz Oh I didn't know that. My bad
Thank you for this. I'll keep that in my mind from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `renderItem` function provides an object to its function. This object does not contain a property named `request`, hence the code

```js
renderItem={({request}) => renderList(request)}
```

does not work. The property is called `item`. Each `item` is one element in the provided `data` array. In this case it is called `requests`.

You need to implement it as follows.

```js
renderItem={({item}) => renderList(item)}
```